# Singularity build error "No such file or directory" while %files is used to copy from host into singularity image

Tags: container

I have the following singularity definition file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:21.08-tf2-py3

%files
    /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
    /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb /tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb

%environment
    export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/kla:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
    export MODEL_PATH="/home/data"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/tensorflow:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/amd-fftw/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

%post
    echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
    dpkg -i /tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb && rm -rf /tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip --no-cache-dir --no-cache install --user -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

As I built the singularity image, I got the following errors: `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/requirements.txt'` and `error: cannot access archive '/tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb': No such file or directory`.

It is my understanding that %files already copied the corresponding files into /tmp in the image. However, as I checked the build log, I saw the following messages: `INFO:    Copying /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/requirements.txt to /tmp/build-temp-687487635/rootfs/tmp/requirements.txt INFO:    Copying /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb to /tmp/build-temp-687487635/rootfs/tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb`.

To see if the two files are really copied to `\tmp`, I specified `ls -l /tmp` in the definition file. The files were not found in `\tmp`. I also searched one of the files by specifying `find / -name aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb` within the definition file, but got the following error: `find: File system loop detected; ‘/tmp/build-temp-565811705/rootfs’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’`.

Comment: `/tmp/build-temp-687487635/rootfs` is the rootfs folder of the future image. That's full path on the **host**, not inside the image. So that's fine and expected, it shows the files were actually copied. I suggest that im the `%post` section, the first command you run is `ls -l /tmp` to check if the files are actually there.

Comment: @aviro It seems that the files are not in ```/tmp```. I also searched one of the files by specifying ```find / -name aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb``` within the definition file, but got the following error: ```find: File system loop detected; ‘/tmp/build-temp-565811705/rootfs’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’```.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the following comment on [github](https://github.com/apptainer/singularity/issues/5848#issuecomment-785242691):

> at build time, `/var/tmp` is being mounted from the host.
>
> 1. The docker image is extracted to disk
> 2. Your file *is* now getting copied into extracted image's `/var/tmp`
> 3. When the build `%post` is run, **the host's tmp directory is mounted into the container. This hides the file that was copied into the extracted image.**
>
> **It should work for paths that are not `/tmp` `/var/tmp` `/home` etc.**

Also [another comment](https://github.com/apptainer/singularity/issues/5514#issuecomment-678107469) from another issue in github:

> ... host /tmp and /var/tmp are mounted on top of /tmp and /var/tmp
> container directories during %post...

You have two options:

1. Copy the files to a different folder instead of `/tmp`, for instance: `/opt`.

```
%files
    /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/requirements.txt /opt/requirements.txt
    /home/zfan/sandbox/Virgo_Algo/DevEnv/AMD/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb /opt/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb

...

%post
    ...
    dpkg -i /opt/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb && rm -rf /opt/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb
    ...
    pip --no-cache-dir --no-cache install --user -r /opt/requirements.txt
```

2. In the `%post` section, use files from `$SINGULARITY_CONTAINER/tmp` instead of `/tmp`.

Since `/tmp` from the host is mounted on `/tmp` inside the container, `$SINGULARITY_CONTAINER` will point to the root filesystem of the container used for the build (`/tmp/build-temp-XXX/rootfs`), and `$SINGULARITY_CONTAINER/tmp` would be `/tmp/build-temp-XXX/rootfs/tmp` from the host, which is where the files were copied to.

```
%post
    ...
    dpkg -i $SINGULARITY_CONTAINER/tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb && rm -rf $SINGULARITY_CONTAINER/tmp/aocl-linux-aocc-2.2.0_1_amd64.deb
    ...
    pip --no-cache-dir --no-cache install --user -r $SINGULARITY_CONTAINER/tmp/requirements.txt
```